# Best way to get aggregates from ranged data

Tags: aggregate, time-series-database

The problem I'm having is as follows:

I have 'shifts' table with the following ranged data I want to make aggregates on:

```
ID   | started_at          | ended_at          | costs
1    |  2022-08-23 08:00   | 2022-08-23 11:00  | 150
2    |  2022-08-23 08:30   | 2022-08-23 09:30  | 50
```

Currently using MySQL, how to get the following data:

```
time             | total_costs  | total_count
2022-08-23 08:00 | 75           | 2
2022-08-23 09:00 | 75           | 2
2022-08-23 10:00 | 50           | 1
```

Or do you recommend using other DB specially built for this kind of data?

**Edit:** sorry for the inconvenience. Time is an interval 2022-08-23 08:00-09:00, 2022-08-23 09:00-10:00, and so on. So the `total_costs` are the `sum(calculated_costs)` for the shifts that fall into the interval.

```
calculated_costs = (cost / total_duration) * duration_in_interval
                   (150 / 3 hours) * 1 hour = 50
```

total_count = the count(*) of shifts that have the started_at and ended_at in/around the current time (interval)

Hope someone kan point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Is 75 some sort of threshold or how do you get two 75s from 150?

Comment: And how do you get 8 & 9 from 8 - 11? Your result from your data makes no sense!

Comment: Final comment - do you want to break it out by the hour? You might want to look at Postgresql's range types - tstzrange for example!

Comment: Added some more information and will look into range types. Thanks.

Comment: Therefore the result should contain 3 x 50 and not 2 x 75? Can you update or explain why not?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, I did the following (all of the code below can be found on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=faea91d1a3f7b8018de9815279977a55)):

I decided to use 2 approaches - a "classic" one and one using PostgreSQL's range types.

### Approach 1 - starttime/endtime

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  t_id       INTEGER   NOT NULL,
  started_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  ended_at   TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  costs      INTEGER   NOT NULL
);
```

- it's worth noting that it's best to get into the habit of using `TIMESTAMPTZ` at **all** times - I've simply used `TIMESTAMP` here because it's that bit more legible and time zones aren't integral to the question.

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(1, '2022-08-23 08:00', '2022-08-23 11:00', 150),
(2, '2022-08-23 08:30', '2022-08-23 09:30',  50);
```

### First step:

```
SELECT
  t_id,
  GENERATE_SERIES(started_at, ended_at - INTERVAL '1 HOUR', '1 HOUR') AS st,
  GENERATE_SERIES(started_at + INTERVAL '1 HOUR', ended_at, '1 HOUR') AS et,
  costs
FROM test;

t_id                   st                    et  costs
1     2022-08-23 08:00:00   2022-08-23 09:00:00    150
1     2022-08-23 09:00:00   2022-08-23 10:00:00    150
1     2022-08-23 10:00:00   2022-08-23 11:00:00    150
2     2022-08-23 08:30:00   2022-08-23 09:30:00     50
```

- we use the incomparable PostgreSQL function [`GENERATE_SERIES`](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/03/14/fun-with-sql-generate-sql/) ([manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html)) - why the other vendors haven't implemented it yet is beyond me.
- there's a bit of jiggery-pokery involved with adding and subtracting hours so that we don't go over the bounds of the `started_at` and `ended_at` timestamps.

### 2nd step:

I've left in extra fields so that you can easily see what's going on - remove as required.

```
WITH hours AS
(
  SELECT
    t_id,
    GENERATE_SERIES(started_at, ended_at - INTERVAL '1 HOUR', '1 HOUR') AS st,
    GENERATE_SERIES(started_at + INTERVAL '1 HOUR', ended_at, '1 HOUR') AS et,
    costs
  FROM test
)
SELECT 
  *,
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t_id),
  costs/COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t_id) AS hourly_cost
FROM hours;
```

Result:

```
t_id                   st                    et  costs  count   hourly_cost
1     2022-08-23 08:00:00   2022-08-23 09:00:00    150      3       50
1     2022-08-23 09:00:00   2022-08-23 10:00:00    150      3       50
1     2022-08-23 10:00:00   2022-08-23 11:00:00    150      3       50
2     2022-08-23 08:30:00   2022-08-23 09:30:00     50      1       50
```

So, as per the data, we can see that each hour of each shift cost 50. I checked with a different cost (600) and got an hourly_cost of 200, so it appears to work generally.

### Approach 2 - PostgreSQL range types

```
CREATE TABLE test2
(
  t_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
  st_et TSRANGE NOT NULL,
  costs INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES
(1, '[2022-08-23 08:00, 2022-08-23 11:00)', 600),  -- <<<=== Note 600!
(2, '[2022-08-23 08:30, 2022-08-23 09:30)',  50);
```

- Note the `[` and `)` part of the timestamp ranges' `INSERT`s. These are [INCLUSIVE and EXCLUSIVE bounds](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INCLUSIVITY), so the first range extends from 2022-08-23 08:00 to the very last instant before 2022-08-23 11:00, but **not** 11:00 itself. This distinguishes it from the approach above where the shifts effectively overlap at the ranges' hourly boundaries.

  This, plus an extensive array of [Range/Multirange Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-range.html) (yes, there's also a multirange type!) can make for some very sophisticated analysis of ranges of dates/times/ints... the world is your oyster! We won't be using them here (well, hardly), but check out some of the examples/sites online - well worth any time spent!
- As with many complex systems, it is sometimes difficult to do simple things - it is only when we delve more deeply that the usefulness and sophistication of the tools become apparent. So it is with multi-range types - the SQL in this case is a bit "hairy"...

The SQL:

```
SELECT
  t_id,
  (
    '[' ||
    GENERATE_SERIES(LOWER(st_et), UPPER(st_et) - INTERVAL '1 HOUR', '1 HOUR')::TEXT ||
    ', ' ||
    GENERATE_SERIES(LOWER(st_et) + INTERVAL '1 HOUR', UPPER(st_et), '1 HOUR')::TEXT ||
    ')'
  )::TSRANGE AS s_range,  -- shift range
  costs
FROM test2;
```

Result:

```
t_id                  s_range                      costs
1   ["2022-08-23 08:00:00","2022-08-23 09:00:00")    600
1   ["2022-08-23 09:00:00","2022-08-23 10:00:00")    600
1   ["2022-08-23 10:00:00","2022-08-23 11:00:00")    600
2   ["2022-08-23 08:30:00","2022-08-23 09:30:00")     50
```

and then it's simply a repeat of the approach taken in Approach 1 - see fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

There is `Round Robin Database` by Tobias Oetiker used for various time series data monitoring/graphing systems like MRTG, Nagios, Munin etc. It has a pretty powerful set of embedded aggregate functions as well as reverse polish notation interpreter for custom calculations. It isn't a database in the usual sense as it is intended to store not an exact data feeded to it, but aggregates based on the data feeded.

https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/

I'm not sure it is the right tool for your purposes but it is a good starting point for the whole concept.